# Arch ARM Pacman not able to connect to servers after "-Syyu"

Tags: linux, arch-linux, arm

I've been searching around in Arch Linux forums and on the specific ones of my device's architecture, without any luck.

Unfortunately, ARM specific Arch Forum is dead...and the main Arch forum wont let me post because they tell me to go to the ARM forum....so I can't find any help there.

I'm using the ARMv7 Arch distro on a Samsung Chromebook 2

Everything was working fine until yesterday. `Pacman` was running and updating everything as expected.

I tried to add the `[multilib]` repo following Arch Wiki instructions (editing `pacman.conf` and adding the details manually)

At this point I did
`pacman -Syyu`

After this, `pacman` started behaving erratically. I was always receiving error to connect to any repo database.
I tried un-commenting manually specific servers from the mirrorlist and removed the `[multilib]` repo from `pacman.conf`

No luck, nothing changed.

So I re-installed `pacman` manually downloading the package with `wget`.

All fine, `pacman` was re-installed successfully and `pacman.conf` is reset to default.

Trying to run `pacman -Syu` to update the system gives me 404 error for ALL servers now.

After trying commenting/un-commenting and manually including servers in `pacman.conf`....no luck.

So my next step was to follow Arch Wiki section to manually re-install/repair `pacman` here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman#Manually_reinstalling_pacman

I downloaded `pacman-static` (and all dependencies), compiled and all went fine with a successful installation.

Now, I'm trying to run `pacman-static` and the system outputs command not found...which makes no sense.

I have no idea what more to do to repair `pacman` or how to run `pacman-static`.

Internet is working fine, `wget` is working fine, browsing is ok.

Here is my current 'pacman.conf'

```
cat /etc/pacman.conf
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
#GPGDir      = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
#HookDir     = /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -L -C - -f -o %o %u
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
Architecture = armv7h

# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =

#NoUpgrade   =
#NoExtract   =

# Misc options
#UseSyslog
#Color
#TotalDownload
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists

# By default, pacman accepts packages signed by keys that its local keyring
# trusts (see pacman-key and its man page), as well as unsigned packages.
SigLevel    = Required DatabaseOptional
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional
#RemoteFileSigLevel = Required

# NOTE: You must run `pacman-key --init` before first using pacman; the local
# keyring can then be populated with the keys of all official Arch Linux ARM
# packagers with `pacman-key --populate archlinuxarm`.

#
# REPOSITORIES
#   - can be defined here or included from another file
#   - pacman will search repositories in the order defined here
#   - local/custom mirrors can be added here or in separate files
#   - repositories listed first will take precedence when packages
#     have identical names, regardless of version number
#   - URLs will have $repo replaced by the name of the current repo
#   - URLs will have $arch replaced by the name of the architecture
#
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

# The testing repositories are disabled by default. To enable, uncomment the
# repo name header and Include lines. You can add preferred servers immediately
# after the header, and they will be used before the default mirrors.

[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[alarm]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[aur]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# An example of a custom package repository.  See the pacman manpage for
# tips on creating your own repositories.
#[custom]
#SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
#Server = file:///home/custompkgs
```

Here is the error I keep receiving for all repositories no matter which server I use:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirrors.evowise.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.rackspace.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.rackspace.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.chaoticum.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.chaoticum.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.f4st.host : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.kku.ac.th : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.kku.ac.th : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror2.totbb.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed to update core (failed to retrieve some files)
```

In the meantime I've run:

```
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate archlinuxarm
```

after re-installing `pacman` to make sure that these are updated too

Please let me know what more details you need to help me debug this issue and repair `pacman`.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried updating the mirror list yet? It may simply be critically out of date. Multilib may also not apply to ARM. It’s usually for x86 libs on x64 systems.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB

Fortunately I found the solution and I have updated in the question

Comment: Please move the solution to the answer section below. We can answer our own questions.

Comment: Please see [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) Solutions don't belong to questions, they belong to answers. You may want to copy the relevant fragment of [revision 2](https://superuser.com/revisions/1649637/2) and form an answer.